# python 3: bytes vs str in mercurial

Tags: python-3.x, mercurial

Here is a case on `bytes` vs `str` in `mercurial` in the following code.

```
from mercurial import hg

schemes = {
    'bundle': hg.bundlerepo,
}


import sys

print(sys.getdefaultencoding())

print('\nhg.schemes:')
print(hg.schemes)

print('\nschemes:')
print(schemes)
```

The output is as the following:

```
utf-8

hg.schemes:
{b'bundle': <module 'mercurial.bundlerepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/bundlerepo.py'>, b'union': <module 'mercurial.unionrepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/unionrepo.py'>, b'file': <function _local at 0x1044547a0>, b'http': <module 'mercurial.httppeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py'>, b'https': <module 'mercurial.httppeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py'>, b'ssh': <module 'mercurial.sshpeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/sshpeer.py'>, b'static-http': <module 'mercurial.statichttprepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/statichttprepo.py'>}

schemes:
{'bundle': <module 'mercurial.bundlerepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/bundlerepo.py'>, 'union': <module 'mercurial.unionrepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/unionrepo.py'>, 'file': <function _local at 0x1044547a0>, 'http': <module 'mercurial.httppeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py'>, 'https': <module 'mercurial.httppeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/httppeer.py'>, 'ssh': <module 'mercurial.sshpeer' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/sshpeer.py'>, 'static-http': <module 'mercurial.statichttprepo' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/statichttprepo.py'>}
```

You can see that the `keys` in `hg.schemes` are `bytes` other than `str` that I couldn't understand. Could anyone explain the issue? The `hg.schemes` is defined as the follows [ https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-all/file/tip/mercurial/hg.py ]:

```
schemes = {
    'bundle': bundlerepo,
    'union': unionrepo,
    'file': _local,
    'http': httppeer,
    'https': httppeer,
    'ssh': sshpeer,
    'static-http': statichttprepo,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following information pretty well explained the case.

The following comment is from `class hgloader(importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader)`, referring [`https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-all/file/tip/mercurial/__init__.py`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-all/file/tip/mercurial/__init__.py)

```
    """Custom module loader that transforms source code.

    When the source code is converted to a code object, we transform
    certain patterns to be Python 3 compatible. This allows us to write code
    that is natively Python 2 and compatible with Python 3 without
    making the code excessively ugly.

    We do this by transforming the token stream between parse and compile.
    Implementing transformations invalidates caching assumptions made
    by the built-in importer. The built-in importer stores a header on
    saved bytecode files indicating the Python/bytecode version. If the
    version changes, the cached bytecode is ignored. The Mercurial
    transformations could change at any time. This means we need to check
    that cached bytecode was generated with the current transformation
    code or there could be a mismatch between cached bytecode and what
    would be generated from this class.

    We supplement the bytecode caching layer by wrapping ``get_data``
    and ``set_data``. These functions are called when the
    ``SourceFileLoader`` retrieves and saves bytecode cache files,
    respectively. We simply add an additional header on the file. As
    long as the version in this file is changed when semantics change,
    cached bytecode should be invalidated when transformations change.

    The added header has the form ``HG<VERSION>``. That is a literal
    ``HG`` with 2 binary bytes indicating the transformation version.
    """
```

The summary behind is from [`https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2017/03/13/from-__past__-import-bytes_literals/`](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2017/03/13/from-__past__-import-bytes_literals/)

> In summary, the hack is a source-transforming module loader for Python. It can be used by Python 3 to import a Python 2 source file while translating certain primitives to their Python 3 equivalents. It is kind of like 2to3 except it executes at run-time during import. The main goal of the hack was to facilitate porting Mercurial to Python 3 while deferring having to make the most invasive - and therefore most annoying - elements of the port in the canonical source code representation.

For more information, you can refer to the follows;

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/rev/1c22400db72d
- https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6195